# How to find Radius of geometry in postgis?

Tags: postgresql, openlayers, gis, postgis

I am trying to develop a GIS application in which i would like to limit the area of geofence of buffer created.

Is there postgis function to find the radius of buffer or bounds of a geofence?

Comment: You're better off posting this sort of thing on http://gis.stackexchange.com/. DO NOT just copy and paste this post - either flag it for migration, or *delete* this one and *then* post on gis.stackexchange.com. (Really, you also need to be a lot more detailed. What data types define your geo-fence? Show the command(s) that you use to create one. Your PostGIS and PostgreSQL versions should also be included.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ST_Envelope to get the extents of a bounding box around some feature, in, the minimum bounding rectangle (MBR).

```
select ST_Astext(ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer(ST_Makepoint(0,0),10)));
```

returns a rectangle not a circle

```
POLYGON((-10 -10,-10 10,10 10,10 -10,-10 -10))
```

You can then use the min and max functions, ST_Xmax, ST_Xmin and the Y equivalents to get the width, height of the MBR.

Is this what you asked?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this wasnt what I asked exactly. I wanted to find if the fence is inside a particular boundary and thought of limiting the radius first. But since it can be done using st_contains the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks John,

I asked the question wrongly, My actual requirement was that the fence must not cross the allowed bounds. I first thought of limiting the radius of fence but it can be done using st_contains since it matches my actual requirement.

```
Select st_contains ((select the_geom from gis.city_border),(select the_geom from geofence))
```

Solved.